# Jekyll uninstall/reinstall - issues with dependancies?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm attempting to use jekyll to build a blog and then deploy it on Amazon S3. My earlier attempts to deploy on github were successful (see http://blog.annof.me):

[image: github-deployed blog]

[Files on github](https://github.com/kescobo/kescobo.github.io)

But since then, I've tried a couple of other things, and at one point I uninstalled jekyll (I think using gem). When I reinstalled jekyll (`gem install jekyll`), a number of dependancies didn't come along (jekyll-coffeescript and some others), and now when I try to build a new site, there are some serious problems with the formatting (see http://annof.me/blog/):

[image: new blog output]

[files on github](https://github.com/kescobo/jekyll-blog)

I think perhaps the uninstall/reinstall screwed something up, but I don't have the technical chops to figure out exactly what's at issue. And I've tried uninstalling jekyll and all of its dependencies, and then reinstalling, but upon reinstall, I have the same problems.

I'm not sure what additional info would be useful - happy to provide it. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Edited to include links to file structure in github.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ site.description }}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.url | replace:'index.html','' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}">
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In _config.yml set the baseurl parameter :

```
baseurl: '/blog'
```

When requesting assets, be sure to do :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/styles.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
or
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/styles.css">
```

And your problem is resolved !

Comment: I've got baseurl: '/blog/', but I'm not sure this is the problem. I've edited the original post to include header code, which has `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">`

Comment: Weird - The comment in the original _config.yml on the line for `baseurl` says "the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/". Sure enough, the built index.htm was pointing to "/blog//css/main.css".

Thanks! It's [working now](http://annof.me/blog/)